# Problem with jdbc in Google Script - "We're sorry, a server error occurred."

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

I try to connect to Oracle Database using `Jdbc.getConnection()` function in Google Script. After checking the connection string, username and password I still get an error

> "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try
>   again."

The connection string is in format `jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP Address:port:SID`

Did some of you have similar issue? What can be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question so others may help you. Also see the [JDBC documentation for Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on connecting to an Oracle Cloud ATP database, but figured this one out along the way.  Here's the example from the Google Apps Scripts docs configured to work against my Oracle XE database.

```
function connect_oracle() {
  const dbUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle-server.net:1521/XE"
  const conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, 'scott', 'tiger');
  const stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
    const results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM redcat.customer');
    const numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

    while (results.next()) {
      let rowString = '';
      for (let col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
        rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
      }
      console.log(rowString);
    }

    results.close();
    stmt.close();
}
```